# How can I specify to which figure a plot should go?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have multiple figures open, and I want to update them independently during runtime. The following toy example should clarify my intention:

```
clf;

figure('name', 'a and b'); % a and b should be plotted to this window
hold on;
ylim([-100, 100]);

figure('name', 'c'); % only c should be plotted to this window

a = 0;
b = [];
for i = 1:100
    a = a + 1;
    b = [b, -i];
    c = b;
    xlim([0, i]);
    plot(i, a, 'o');
    plot(i, b(i), '.r');
    drawnow;
end
```

The problem here is that when I open the second `figure`, I cannot tell the `plot` functions to plot to the first one instead of the second (and only `c` should be plotted to the second).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use something like

```
figure(1)
plot(x,y) % this will go on figure 1

figure(2)
plot(z,w) % this will go on another figure
```

The command will also set the figure visible and on top of everything.

You can switch back and forth between the figures as necessary by issuing the same `figure` command. Alternatively, you can use the handle to the figure as well:

```
h=figure(...)
```

and then issue `figure(h)` instead of using numeric indices. With this syntax, you can also prevent the figure from popping up on top by using

```
set(0,'CurrentFigure',h)
```

Answer (score 15):

You can specify the axes-object in the plot-command. See here:

> http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html

So, open a figure, insert the axes, save the id of the axes object, and then plot into it:

```
figure
hAx1 = axes;
plot(hAx1, 1, 1, '*r')
hold on

figure
hAx2 = axes;
plot(hAx2, 2, 1, '*r')
hold on


plot(hAx2, 3, 4, '*b')
plot(hAx1, 3, 3, '*b')
```

Alternatively, you can use `gca` instead of creating the axes object yourself (because it's automatically created within the actual figure, when it doesn't exist!)

```
figure
plot(1,1)
hAx1 = gca;
hold on

figure
plot(2,2)

plot(hAx1, 3, 3)
```

---

See the following hierarchy representing the relationship between figures and axes

[image]

From http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html.

Comment: But why manipulate the axis? What if I don't want axes at all? This seems a bit convoluted for me (new to Matlab). Could you please explain?

Comment: Because something you plot ALWAYS goes into an axes-object (you can't plot without axes) ;) When you don't use `axes`-command, `plot` automatically creates them when the figure doesn't contain them. So it's the right way to go. see my edited post!

Comment: Thanks, but I still wonder, why the `plot` command uses the axis handle instead of the figure handle - it would seem to be more intuitive.

Comment: There are often multiple axes per figure.  See `subplot`.