# How to show image and plot simultaneously in loop

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to show image and plot in the loop. I want to show image in one figure and plot in other figure. So I try to use my code, but it does not work. Could you help me fix it? Thanks so much

```
x=0;
x_arr=[]
I=imread('peppers.png');
figure
for i=1:100
    if mod(i,10)==0
    pause(0.5);
    x=i.^2+1;
    x_arr=[x_arr x]
   %show image
    hold on
    imshow(I);
    hold off
    %show plot
    pause(0.5);
    hold on
    plot(y_arr);
    hold off
    end
end
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`figure` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html). Also, take a look at this question/answer on [How can I specify to which figure a plot should go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532775/how-can-i-specify-to-which-figure-a-plot-should-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do so by using figure for handeling 2 windows:

```
x=0;
x_arr=[]
I=imread('peppers.png');

for i=1:100
    if mod(i,10)==0
    pause(0.5);
    x=i.^2+1;
    x_arr=[x_arr x];
   %show image

   figure(1)
    imshow(I);

    %show plot
    pause(0.5);
    figure(2)
    plot(x_arr);
    end
end
```

or by using subplots to keep it in one window:

```
x=0; x_arr=[] 
I=imread('peppers.png'); 
figure (1) 
for i=1:100
    if mod(i,10)==0
    pause(0.5);
    x=i.^2+1;
    x_arr=[x_arr x]    %show image
    subplot(1,2,1);
    imshow(I);

    %show plot
    pause(0.5);
    subplot(1,2,2)
    plot(x_arr);
    end 
 end
```